# If null statement in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to say if this `makeCodeNumber` is defined and is not null use this

```
<cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber#">
```

but if it is null (or empty) then use this

```
<cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclemake#">
```

**All the code**

```
<cfif isDefined("session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber")>
  <cfif len(trim("session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber"))>
    <cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber#">
  <cfelse>
    <cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclemake#">
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I am showing that it is null (or empty string) when I dump the variables but for some reason I must be overlooking something because when it is null it still is only going by `<cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber#">` Instead of `<cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclemake#">`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rather than isDefined() it's preferable to use structKeyExists.  See http://corfield.org/entry/isdefined_vs_structkeyexists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're evaluating the `len(trim())` of the string "session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber" not the value of the variable `session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber`. You need to remove your `"` in your second if statement

```
<cfif isDefined("session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber")>
  <cfif len(trim(session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber))>
    <cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.makeCodeNumber#">
  <cfelse>
    <cfpdfformparam name="make" value="#session.checkout.vehicle.vehiclemake#">
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: @ZaneZ - Though there is nothing technically wrong with it, try and avoid nested statements if they are not really needed, as it decreases readability.